# What is the best and optimise use of struct in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, struct, swift3

**EDITED**

I have to create a struct which takes multiple input parameters. Below is my struct's current structure.

```
struct TTFBCard {

public var id:String
public var userId:String
public var imgUrl:String
public var audioData:String
public var displayText:TTLocaleString
public var messageText:TTLocaleString
public var resStartTime:String
public var resEndTime:String
public var subCards:NSArray
public var type:String
private var _rawTime:TimeInterval?
private var _order:Int?

init(id:String,userId:String,imgUrl:String,audioData:String,displayText:TTLocaleString,messageText:TTLocaleString,resStartTime:String,resEndTime:String,subCards:NSArray,type:String) {
    self.id = id
    self.userId = userId
    self.imgUrl = imgUrl
    self.audioData = audioData
    self.displayText = displayText
    self.messageText = messageText
    self.resStartTime = resStartTime
    self.resEndTime = resEndTime
    self.subCards = subCards
    self.type = type
}
```

}

It really looks bad to send too many parameters. Any suggestion, please!

Comment: Why is it that long? Could it be initialized from a dictionary (maybe from JSON, plist, etc.) instead, with all its values?

Comment: I am using Google Firebase.

Comment: That one is not your current structure, but its init

Comment: Can't you externally create a tuple and pass it as argument?

Comment: Hey @3000, can you please give me an example?

Comment: `typealias params = (first:String, second:String, third:String)
    
let actualParams:params = ("a", "b", "c")

struct myStruct {
 var A:String
 var B:String
 var C:String
 
 init(tuple:params){
  A = tuple.0
  B = tuple.1
  C = tuple.2
 }
 
}

var s = myStruct(tuple:actualParams)
print(s)
print(s.A)`